# Is there a way to specify which drawable folder a device should use?

Tags: android, drawable

For reasons that I don't get both Xyboards (10" & 8") are ignoring all the art I have in my xhdpi folder and pulling the art from the hdpi folder, instead.  I can obviously rename all my files with "_xhdpi" or some such kluge, but was hoping that there's some universal setting that I'm overlooking whereby I can detect the actual resolution and instruct the device which folder to get its art from.

Comment: Are you sure these devices aren't hdpi?

Comment: On the contrary, I'm sure they *are hdpi (I just don't understand why). But if they are hdpi and a razr maxx (a phone with much lower res) is hdpi, then how do I split up the art for the two?

Comment: Well all I know is that that's done automatically when using the different folders. If your devices are fetching from the correct folder there shouldn't be a problem :p Are you saying your hdpi-images look terrible?

Comment: yeah... the devices have dramatically different resolutions, and *absolutely need two different sets of art.  You know how most Android applications looks kind of "soft"? I suspect this is because generally people take advantage of Android's excellent scaling abilities, but if you need an app to look really crisp, you *have to tailor the art to the specific range of resolutions, and it's loony to pull the same art for phones as for tablets (even for the very high res phones) cause the tablets are ~30% more resolute.

Comment: Then you do indeed need an answer to your question =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see what density your device thinks it is by looking at the [`DisplayMetrics` density](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#density).  That's where the device will look first for resources.

I can't find the reference right now, but I'm pretty sure the value of `density` in that class for mdpi is 1.0, hdpi is 1.5, and xhdpi is 2.0.

Remember that screens also have a size which is independent of the density.  If you're trying to account for different screen sizes only with art density, you're doing it wrong.  Ideally, a `large-mdpi` image and a `large-hdpi` image will be approximately the same size when measured with a plastic ruler on the screen, but the `hdpi` image should look nicer on account of having more pixels.  You can have [more refined size qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) than just "large screen" and "normal screen".  That might do what you want.

Comment: thanks, I actually understand all this... my question is, is there a dynamic way (simply by placing art in different folders) to get the devices to pull the art from the folder of my choice, seeing as how they don't seem to differentiate between what they think of as phone high-res and tablet high-res.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel Edited to add another possible solution.  If you're not trusting the device to classify itself into the right bucket, how do you *want* to determining what art to use?

Comment: well, what I'm doing now is just looking at the screen width when my first activity starts and if its >1200 (it's in landscape mode) then I know its a tablet.

Answer (score 0):

Install this app, to check the device dpi and size screen.

[ScreenInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jotabout.screeninfo&hl=en)

With that info you can organize your layouts/drawables.

For example the GalaxyTab has: Large Screen/hdpi and the Motorola Xoom Xlarge Screen/mdpi

Comment: sorry, could you please elaborate? I don't need extra info on how to get a device's dpi, but what is this about Large Screen/hdpi? Is that a folder naming convention? If so, could you point me to a link that documents these? Cause I don't see anything like this in the official google docs.

Comment: Sure, check this post: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: right, so that post is a tad confusing but it's not saying what you're saying. It's saying that I can make different layouts for different displays, but I'm not talking about layouts, I'm talking about the art itself.